# unable to load GridOption's rowdata values

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getallAnimesReviews();
    //this.gridOption=this.getGridOptions();
    // console.log('gridoptioncsd',this.gridOption);
  }
  
  public getallAnimesReviews(){
    this.animeservice.getallAnimesReviews()
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.Anime = response;
        console.log('Anime',this.Anime);
        
        this.gridOption=this.getGridOptions();
        // this.gridOption.api?.setRowData(this.Anime); 
        console.log('gridoptioncsd',this.gridOption);
      }
    )
  }
```

when i'm calling the gridoptions inside ngoninit rhe rowdata is shown as undefined and when i'm calling the gridoption inside getallAnimesReviews function the rowdata are getting assigned but on ui i'm getting loading..[please refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgeeS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more code around what's happening with the grid? Typically you'd expect to see a callback from grid for when it's ready.

On this callback, without looking at the docs, I believe they tend to return the api and the column api, something like this:

```js
public onGridReady(api: GridApi, colApi: ColumnApi): void {
    this._gridApi = api;
    this._colApi = colApi;
}
```

Store those API services they've given once the grid has loaded, and then use that - not the options - to interact with the grid for after it's been initialised.

The options are only for initial setup, after that, you need to use the given APIs to update/alter the grid and its data.

Obviously not like this because I'm not looking at the docs for the exacts, but it's the API, not the options to deal with:

```js
response =>
    this._api.setData(response);
```